How to split values in a varchar column to multiple rows in SQL?
I have a table which has a column 1 containing values such as 01.02.2001;16.07.2003;25.08.2005 belong to person of ID = 1, that looks like this



Person_ID
Column_1




1
01.02.2001;16.07.2003;25.08.2005



These are 3 dates separated by a ;
I would like to split the dates in to 3 rows such that all of them will still have the person of ID 1
This is how I want the end result to look like:



Person_ID
Column_1




1
01.02.2001


1
16.07.2003


1
25.08.2005



I tried CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Column_1, ';') but it did not give the expected results. I don't know if it is a Microsoft SQL query but the result it gave me was basically duplicated the row 3 times.



Person_ID
Column_1




1
01.02.2001;16.07.2003;25.08.2005


1
01.02.2001;16.07.2003;25.08.2005


1
01.02.2001;16.07.2003;25.08.2005




Could you edit your question and include the query you tried so far ? MySQL does not have a STRING_SPLIT function

CSV -> REPLACE() -> JSON array -> JSON_TABLE() -> one value per row.

STRING_SPLIT is the way to go, but you need to select the Value column from it, since Column_1 doesn't contains the splitted string

Please fix your tags: MySQL <> SQL Server

@YitzhakKhabinsky See OP's comment under my answer.

Your attempt works fine for me: db<>fiddle

WITH cte (Person_ID, Column_1) AS (
  SELECT 1, '01.02.2001;16.07.2003;25.08.2005'
  )
SELECT cte.Person_ID, jsontable.Column_1
FROM cte
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(cte.Column_1, ';', '","'), '"]'),
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (Column_1 VARCHAR(255) PATH '$')) jsontable;




Person_ID
Column_1




1
01.02.2001


1
16.07.2003


1
25.08.2005



fiddle


Is there a rather simple sql function for microsoft sql that can give the same results without need to use json_table? – Jani

WITH cte (Person_ID, Column_1) AS (
  SELECT 1, '01.02.2001;16.07.2003;25.08.2005'
  )
SELECT Person_ID, value Column_1
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(cte.Column_1, ';');




Person_ID
Column_1




1
01.02.2001


1
16.07.2003


1
25.08.2005



fiddle

Thank you so much. Is there a rather simple sql function for microsoft sql  that can give the same results without need to use json_table?

@Jani Easily. Added.

@jani what about this one?
